# Crystal report or other alternative for Visual Studio Code

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-code

Is it true that Crystal Report no longer works with Visual Studio Code? If yes, is there any other alternative that is compatible with the VS Code? Many thanks.

Comment: What did Crystal Report do?  Was it an extension for VScode?

Comment: It is a reporting program. I guess it is similar to the MS Reporting Services. It used to appear in the old Visual Studio.